# Griddle v1.3.1 - Sort specific columns using dropdown select

Tags: sorting, reactjs, griddle

i am trying to achieve sorting using a custom dropdown select component instead of the default arrows next to the column headings to sort specific columns. How is it possible?[image]

Comment: I have the same question. Did you got your solution?

Comment: There is not a straightforward way to do this.

You would need to write a new plugin to add the new sort component.